# Display Flash message before session destroy

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Working on two side admin and customer when admin delete any customer that time customer logout from portal with some flash message how can manage from controller.

```
 function __construct() {

    parent::__construct ();

            if(empty($account_arr)){

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('danger_alert',gettext("Your account has been deactive please contact to your administrator"));
        $this->session->sess_destroy ();
        redirect ( base_url ()."login/");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't if you want the flash in the next request. The flash is stored in the session, if you destroy the session, it no longer exists. If you definitely need to destroy the session, you need to store it some other way.

Comment: Handle this in the place you are redirecting _to_ … Put some flag in your session to indicate that it needs to be destroyed, check that flag when you arrive at `base_url ()."login/"`, and then destroy the session there … after you have shown the flash message.